# how to resolve Transformer model DistilBert error got an unexpected keyword argument 'special_tokens_mask'

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am using

Apple Mac M1

OS: MacOS Monterey

Python 3.10.4

I am trying to implement a vector search with DistilBERT and Weaviate by following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-sub-50ms-neural-search-with-distilbert-and-weaviate-4857ae390154)

below is the code setup

```
import nltk
import os
import random
import time
import torch
import weaviate
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

torch.set_grad_enabled(False)

# udpated to use different model if desired
MODEL_NAME = "distilbert-base-uncased"
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
model.to('cuda') # remove if working without GPUs
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

# initialize nltk (for tokenizing sentences)
nltk.download('punkt')

# initialize weaviate client for importing and searching
client = weaviate.Client("http://localhost:8080")

def get_post_filenames(limit_objects=100):
    file_names = []
    i=0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./data/20news-bydate-test"):
        for filename in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_names += [path]
        
    random.shuffle(file_names)
    limit_objects = min(len(file_names), limit_objects)
      
    file_names = file_names[:limit_objects]

    return file_names

def read_posts(filenames=[]):
    posts = []
    for filename in filenames:
        f = open(filename, encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore')
        post = f.read()
        
        # strip the headers (the first occurrence of two newlines)
        post = post[post.find('\n\n'):]
        
        # remove posts with less than 10 words to remove some of the noise
        if len(post.split(' ')) < 10:
               continue
        
        post = post.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', ' ').strip()
        if len(post) > 1000:
            post = post[:1000]
        posts += [post]

    return posts       


def text2vec(text):
    tokens_pt = tokenizer(text, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=500, add_special_tokens = True, return_tensors="pt")
    tokens_pt.to('cuda') # remove if working without GPUs
    outputs = model(**tokens_pt)
    return outputs[0].mean(0).mean(0).detach()

def vectorize_posts(posts=[]):
    post_vectors=[]
    before=time.time()
    for i, post in enumerate(posts):
        vec=text2vec(sent_tokenize(post))
        post_vectors += [vec]
        if i % 100 == 0 and i != 0:
            print("So far {} objects vectorized in {}s".format(i, time.time()-before))
    after=time.time()
    
    print("Vectorized {} items in {}s".format(len(posts), after-before))
    
    return post_vectors

def init_weaviate_schema():
    # a simple schema containing just a single class for our posts
    schema = {
        "classes": [{
                "class": "Post",
                "vectorizer": "none", # explicitly tell Weaviate not to vectorize anything, we are providing the vectors ourselves through our BERT model
                "properties": [{
                    "name": "content",
                    "dataType": ["text"],
                }]
        }]
    }

    # cleanup from previous runs
    client.schema.delete_all()

    client.schema.create(schema)

def import_posts_with_vectors(posts, vectors, batchsize=256):
    batch = weaviate.ObjectsBatchRequest()

    for i, post in enumerate(posts):
        props = {
            "content": post,
        }
        batch.add(props, "Post", vector=vectors[i])
        
        # when either batch size is reached or we are at the last object
        if (i !=0 and i % batchsize == 0) or i == len(posts) - 1:
            # send off the batch
            client.batch.create(batch)
            
            # and reset for the next batch
            batch = weaviate.ObjectsBatchRequest() 
    

def search(query="", limit=3):
    before = time.time()
    vec = text2vec(query)
    vec_took = time.time() - before

    before = time.time()
    near_vec = {"vector": vec.tolist()}
    res = client \
        .query.get("Post", ["content", "_additional {certainty}"]) \
        .with_near_vector(near_vec) \
        .with_limit(limit) \
        .do()
    search_took = time.time() - before

    print("\nQuery \"{}\" with {} results took {:.3f}s ({:.3f}s to vectorize and {:.3f}s to search)" \
          .format(query, limit, vec_took+search_took, vec_took, search_took))
    for post in res["data"]["Get"]["Post"]:
        print("{:.4f}: {}".format(post["_additional"]["certainty"], post["content"]))
        print('---')

# run everything
init_weaviate_schema()
posts = read_posts(get_post_filenames(4000))
vectors = vectorize_posts(posts)
import_posts_with_vectors(posts, vectors)

search("the best camera lens", 1)
search("which software do i need to view jpeg files", 1)
search("windows vs mac", 1)
```

the fuction below trigger errors

```
def text2vec(text):
    # tokens_pt = tokenizer(text, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=500, add_special_tokens = True, return_tensors="pt")
    tokens_pt = tokenizer.encode_plus(text, add_special_tokens = True,    truncation = True, padding = "max_length", return_attention_mask = True, return_tensors = "pt")

    tokens_pt.to('cuda') # remove if working without GPUs
    outputs = model(**tokens_pt)
    return outputs[0].mean(0).mean(0).detach()
```

> > error 1
> >
> > > tokens_pt.to('cuda') # remove if working without GPUs
> > > AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to'

when I comment out the GPU

```
#tokens_pt.to('cuda')
```

and run the code. I get this error

> > error 2
> >
> > > outputs = model(**tokens_pt)
> > > File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/py310a/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
> > > return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
> > > TypeError: DistilBertModel.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'special_tokens_mask'

what is causing this errors and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your errors on my environment (Ubuntu), but from what I see, I'd suggest to try adding the `return_special_tokens_mask=False` parameter:

```py
tokens_pt = tokenizer.encode_plus(
    text, 
    add_special_tokens=True,
    truncation=True,
    padding="max_length",
    return_attention_mask=True,
    return_tensors="pt",
    return_special_tokens_mask=False
)
```

If that fails, try to remove it explicitly:

```py
tokens_pt.pop("special_tokens_mask")
```

Comment: i'm still getting the same error "TypeError: DistilBertModel.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'special_tokens_mask'"

Comment: Try to remove it after tokenization then, `tokens_pt.pop("special_tokens_mask")`